# How can i get contacts from Google Plus API using Oauth2.0

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, google-api, google-plus, google-api-java-client

I have got accesstoken using oauth2.0.  How can i get the list of contacts for that user .

Could any one please paste some sample code or any suggestions on how to get the contact list from google plus API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google plus API as of now only vends out publicly exposed data of the user. You will not be able to obtain any data that is private using the Plus Scope. Your best bet would be to use google-contacts-api by adding it to your scope.

EDIT: Looks like google release a plus API now. Please refer the comments

Comment: Actually google released a google plus api https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/userId/people/collection (where list is circle) to get list of friends in the specified circle. The reference for the api is https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list